# alternating series where $0<x<1$ , then $1-x+{x}^2-\dots=$ (?)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$0<x<1$ , then $1-x+{x}^2-\dots=$ $L$    $-(i)$

This is as much as I can say about this series:

Rewriting the series as $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n}x^{n} $$
Ignoring the sign, I know that (i) is a geometric series and it would converge to $\dfrac1{1-x}$. Also, the terms are nonincreasing and they converge to $0$. Hence by the alternating series test, (i) is convergent.

It should satisfy this (I even checked by taking the two subsequences $S_{2n+1}$ and $S_{2n}$ of the partial sum sequence)
$$ \displaystyle| S_k - L | \leq a_{k+1} $$

I still can't understand how to use this information to find $L$ which is given to be $\dfrac1{1+x}$

Comment: It's just an infinite geometric series with common ratio $-x$.

Comment: Simply use the geometric series with ratio $-x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $L=1-x+{x}^2-\cdots$ converges for $|x|<1$

then $xL= x-x^2+{x}^3-\cdots$ also converges for $|x|<1$

and $L+xL = 1$

so $L=\frac{1}{1+x}$ for $|x|<1$

Answer (score 1):

L$= 1−x+x^2−⋯$
$=(1+x^2+x^4+⋯) − (x+x^3+x^5⋯)$
$=(1+x^2+x^4+⋯) − x(1+x^2+x^4⋯)$
$=(1+x^2+x^4+⋯)(1−x)$
$=\frac{1}{(1-x^2)}(1-x)$
$=\frac{1}{1+x}$
So, L$=\frac{1}{1+x}$